# Prove that closed intervals are a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: analysis

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \leq b$, prove that the closed interval $[a,b]$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. Use the fact that every infinite subset of a compact metric space has a limit point.

I know that using Heine-Borel theorem if a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded then it is compact, but I'm not sure how to prove the problem using the given fact.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with an open cover?

Comment: Do you mean a **compact** metric space in that said fact? Otherwise I am not sure that it's correct.

Comment: Yes, I will make the edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Let $X$ be an infinite subset of $[a,b]$. Divide $[a,b]$ into two halves $[a,(a+b)/2]$ and $[(a+b)/2, b]$, of equal length. One of these halves must contain infinitely many points of $X$. Choose that half, and divide it in half again. By repeating this process, we obtain a nested sequence of intervals $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset \cdots$ such that the length of $I_k$ is $(b-a)/2^k$, and $I_k$ contains infinitely many points of $X$. The set $\cap_k I_k$ contains exactly one point, and it's easy to verify that this point is a limit point of $X$.